# How to Compare Destination Folders names with specific Single Source folder name?

Tags: google-apps-script

Presently, I've been trying to copy the files or folder with files from the source lastcreated folder into the destination folder by comparing the foldername on the basis of the last date created folder. Now I want to compare the source's last date created folder by name with all destination folders, if folder by same name exits than copy the data else create a new folder by same sourcefoldername and copy the contents.

By the help of StackOverflow community, I'm able to compare folder's on basis of last date created and copy the contents but now I want to compare the source last date created foldername with the destination's all folder. If folder by same exits than copy the data in it else it creates a new folder. Attached is the code for getting last date created folder and comparinng with destination folder.

```
var destSubFolders = destLastFolder.getFolders();   
var destSubArray=[];   
while(destSubFolders.hasNext()) {     
  var destSubfolder = destSubFolders.next(); 
  destSubArray.push({
    value: destSubfolder.getDateCreated().valueOf(), 
    sourceFolderId: destSubfolder.getId()
  }); 
}   
destSubArray.sort(function(a,b){return b.value-a.value;}); // Comparing between the date created and extracts the last created folder.    
var destLastSubFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(destSubArray[0].sourceFolderId);// gets the last created sub folder by id.  
var destinationLastSubFolderFiles= destLastSubFolder.getFiles();//get files of the last created subfolder. 
var d_SubName = destLastSubFolder.getName(); // get name of the last created subfolder.  
if(s_SubName == d_SubName ) { //condition for comapring source and destination last created subfolder names.
  var dfnA=[]; // getting files from source sub folder and copying into destination folder.   
  while(destinationLastSubFolderFiles.hasNext()) {
    var dF=destinationLastSubFolderFiles.next();    
    dfnA.push(dF.getName());    
  }
  while(sourceLastSubFolderFiles.hasNext()) {    
    var sF=sourceLastSubFolderFiles.next();    
    if(dfnA.indexOf(sF.getName())==-1) {      
      sF.makeCopy(sF.getName(),destLastSubFolder); // copying files after comparing by names.
    }
  }
} else { //creates new folder by source subfolder name and copies data into new created folder.    
  var sNewName = lastSubFolder.getName();    
  var dFolderName=destLastFolder.createFolder(sNewName);    
  while(sourceLastSubFolderFiles.hasNext()) {       
    var sFilesIterator=sourceLastSubFolderFiles.next();    
    sFilesIterator.makeCopy(sFilesIterator.getName(),dFolderName); // copying files after comparing by names.
  }  
}
```

I need a comparison of source folder name with destination all folder names and if matches then only copy the contents else create a new folder and contents.

Comment: "I need" is not a question...What's the question?

Comment: What do you want to do if there are matching files/subfolders names inside the folder you want to copy the contents to? Should these be duplicated? Or overwritten? Or not copied at all?

Comment: @cooper sorry.  I want to compare my source last created subfolder name with all the subfolder names of destination folder. If there is a match by name then it'll only copy the contents from source subfolder to destination subfolder else it'll create a new subfolder in the destination folder and will copy the contents.

Comment: That is the question that which array function should I use for comparing all the folder names with only a single same?

Comment: The you should add modify your question.

Comment: s_SubName is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function findSubFolderWithLastDate(startingFolderId) {
  var startingFolderId=startingFolderId||'defaultId';
  var startFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(startingFolderId);
  var srcFldrs=startFolder.getFolders();
  var fldrA=[];
  while(srcFldrs.hasNext()) {
    var srcFldr=srcFldrs.next();
    fldrA.push({value:srcFldr.getLastUpdated().valueOf(),id:srcFldr.getId(),name:srcFldr.getName()})
  }
  return fldrA.sort(function(a,b){return(b.value-a.value);})[0].id;
}

function copyingFilesFromSourceToDestinationFolderWithSameName(srcfldrId,desfldrId) {
  var desFldr=DriveApp.getFolderById(desfldrId);
  var srcFldr=DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfldrId);
  var srcSubFldrs=srcFldr.getFolders();
  while(srcSubFldrs.hasNext()) {
    var srcSubFldrFound=false;
    var srcSubFldr=srcSubFldrs.next();
    var desSubFldrs=desFldr.getFolders();
    while(desSubFldrs.hasNext()) {
      var desSubFldr=desSubFldrs.next();
      if(desSubFldr.getName()==srcSubFldr.getName()) {
        srcSubFldrFound=true;
        var files=srcSubFldr.getFiles();
        while(files.hasNext()) {
          var file=files.next();
          file.makeCopy(file.getName(),desSubFldr);
        }
        break;
      } 
    }
    if(!srcSubFldrFound) {
      var newFldr=desFldr.createFolder(srcSubFldr.getName());
      var files=srcSubFldr.getFiles();
      while(files.hasNext()) {
        var file=files.next();
        file.makeCopy(file.getName(),newFldr)
      }
    }
  }
}
```